# How to document contract-last (via jaxb schemagen) webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, schemagen

I've developed a webservice and rightfully my users would like to see documentation. I'd prefer to simply document my code, either with javadoc comments or with an explicit annotation, e.g.

```
@XmlComment("This is used to [blah blah]")
@XmlElement(name = "referenceDate", namespace = NAMESPACE, type = Date.class)
public void setReferenceDate(Date referenceDate) {
    this.referenceDate = referenceDate;
}
```

or

```
/**
 * This is used to [blah blah]
 */
@XmlElement(name = "referenceDate", namespace = NAMESPACE, type = Date.class)
public void setReferenceDate(Date referenceDate) {
    this.referenceDate = referenceDate;
}
```

The above aren't supported, as evidenced here:

- [JAXB-273](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-273?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab) - 2006 request to make xs:documentation elements from annotations
- [JAXB-369](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-369?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab) - 2007 request to make xs:documentation elements from comments
- [SO-470001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470001/jaxb-documentation-annotation) - "You can't do that" stackoverflow question

So I understand I can't use the above to I comment my service. But... Surely there's still a way to do so in a non-manual fashion. Must I hand-craft all my XML just for this? If *that* is the answer, why isn't there more attention on getting this feature into JAXB? Seems downright mandatory for an enterprise-grade webservice, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right it's poor. Most focus these days is on contract-first, so I guess it's not been prioritized. You could use XSLT to add in the comments to the WSDL from a separate XML doc. Not as good as generating it from the Java code, but better than nothing. Here's an ancient posting doing it http://www.gridlab.org/WorkPackages/wp-5/guide/wsdltips.html