# Add description to JAXB @XmlElement ?

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I am doing java-first web service development. I want to add description to @XmlElement for a field so that the generated WSDL will contain documentation for the field.

It seems you can't do this with @XmlElement. Don't know why Oracle doesn't support it.

If I choose another binding other than JAXB, can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use a JAXB annotation so the documentation details will be included in the generated schema (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470001/jaxb-documentation-annotation))

You can use [CXF custom annotations](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/annotations.html), but are only available for ports and operations

```
@WebService
@WSDLDocumentationCollection(
    {
        @WSDLDocumentation("My portType documentation"),
        @WSDLDocumentation(value = "My top level documentation",
                           placement = WSDLDocumentation.Placement.TOP),
        @WSDLDocumentation(value = "My binding doc",
                           placement = WSDLDocumentation.Placement.BINDING)
    }
)
public interface MyService {

    @WSDLDocumentation("The docs for echoString")
    String echoString(String s);

}
```

Comment: Cool. Btw, is there any JIRA issue that tracks the requirement of CXF's another documentation annotation for WebParams and XmlElements ?

Comment: There are some issues reported that you can see searching by free text `@WSDLDocumentation`. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6291?jql=text%20~%20%22%40WSDLDocumentation%22 I think CXF-6291 is similar to your request. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6291